# rust: idiomatic use of generics when using a filetype-dependent writer

Tags: rust, generics

Simplified from https://github.com/132nd-vWing/tacview-splitter.

External dependencies: `zip` crate

The code would do the following:

1. read a file from disk (determined at runtime)
2. analyze the content, split it into a header and a body
3. divide the body into two categories (here blue and red)
4. for each category, write the header and the corresponding body to a separate file
5. the output file type depends on the input file type.

   1. if the input was a txt file, write the output to a txt file
   2. otherwise the input was a txt file contained in a zip file. Write the data as a txt in a zip.

Code is this:

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::io::Write;

struct Descriptors<T: Write> {
    blue: T,
    red: T,
}

struct OutputFilenames {
    pub txt: FilenamesVariant,
    pub zip: FilenamesVariant,
}

struct FilenamesVariant {
    pub blue: String,
    pub red: String,
}

impl Descriptors<zip::ZipWriter<fs::File>> {
    pub fn new(filenames: OutputFilenames) -> Descriptors<zip::ZipWriter<fs::File>> {
        let options =
            zip::write::FileOptions::default().compression_method(zip::CompressionMethod::Deflated);

        let file = fs::File::create(&filenames.zip.blue).unwrap();
        let mut blue = zip::ZipWriter::new(file);
        blue.start_file(&filenames.txt.blue, options).unwrap();

        let file = fs::File::create(&filenames.zip.red).unwrap();
        let mut red = zip::ZipWriter::new(file);
        red.start_file(&filenames.txt.red, options).unwrap();

        Descriptors { blue, red }
    }
}

impl Descriptors<fs::File> {
    pub fn new(filenames: OutputFilenames) -> Descriptors<fs::File> {
        let blue = fs::File::create(&filenames.txt.blue).unwrap();
        let red = fs::File::create(&filenames.txt.red).unwrap();
        Descriptors { blue, red }
    }
}

impl<T: Write> Descriptors<T> {
    fn write(&mut self, header: Vec<String>, blue: Vec<String>, red: Vec<String>) {
        for line in &header {
            writeln!(self.blue, "{}", line).unwrap();
            writeln!(self.red, "{}", line).unwrap();
        }
        for line in &blue {
            writeln!(self.blue, "{}", line).unwrap();
        }
        for line in &red {
            writeln!(self.red, "{}", line).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

impl OutputFilenames {
    fn default() -> Self {
        let txt = FilenamesVariant {
            blue: "blue.txt".to_string(),
            red: "red.txt".to_string(),
        };
        let zip = FilenamesVariant {
            blue: "blue.zip".to_string(),
            red: "red.zip".to_string(),
        };
        Self { txt, zip }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let is_zip = true; // in practice this would be read from disk
    let output_filenames = OutputFilenames::default();

    let header = vec!["some header".to_string(), "headers".to_string()];

    let blue_content = vec!["blue content".to_string(), "blue".to_string()];
    let red_content = vec!["red content".to_string(), "red".to_string()];

    if is_zip {
        let mut descriptors = Descriptors::<zip::ZipWriter<fs::File>>::new(output_filenames);
        descriptors.write(header, blue_content, red_content);
    } else {
        let mut descriptors = Descriptors::<fs::File>::new(output_filenames);
        descriptors.write(header, blue_content, red_content);
    }
}
```

I tried to write the code in manner that would avoid code repetition, by implementing it in a `Descriptor<T: Write>` struct. This struct holds the descriptors independent of the output file type. Then in the main code, I can simple `write` to the descriptors without having to care for the exact type.

Is it possible to write the code in a more generic / concise / idiomatic manner?

What else would you change about this code and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's quite good, and I only have a single nitpick:

- use `&[T] where T: AsRef<str>` instead of `Vec<String>` for your function arguments (that's a general rule, use the least specific possible type in your arguments for maximum compatibility)

Everything else is honestly opinion based, like:

- I would probably not handle `blue` and `red` as two separate things, because all of their code is duplicated. They can be handled as the same thing.
- I'd employ `Box` to become even more type-agnostic and store things only by their trait
- I don't see a big advantage of having all those structs, I think for this case simple functions are more suited

Something like this:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, Write};

use zip::{write::FileOptions, CompressionMethod, ZipWriter};

fn create_filewriter(filename: &str) -> File {
    File::create(filename).unwrap()
}

fn create_zipwriter(filename: &str, nested_filename: &str) -> ZipWriter<File> {
    let mut writer = ZipWriter::new(create_filewriter(filename));
    writer
        .start_file(
            nested_filename,
            FileOptions::default().compression_method(CompressionMethod::Deflated),
        )
        .unwrap();
    writer
}

fn create_writer(zip: bool, name: &str) -> Box<dyn Write> {
    if zip {
        Box::new(create_zipwriter(
            &format!("{name}.zip"),
            &format!("{name}.txt"),
        ))
    } else {
        Box::new(create_filewriter(&format!("{name}.txt")))
    }
}

trait StringsWriter {
    fn write_strings<S: AsRef<str>>(&mut self, lines: &[S]) -> Result<(), io::Error>;
}

impl<T> StringsWriter for T
where
    T: Write,
{
    fn write_strings<S: AsRef<str>>(&mut self, lines: &[S]) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        for line in lines {
            writeln!(self, "{}", line.as_ref())?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let is_zip = true; // in practice this would be read from disk

    let header = vec!["some header".to_string(), "headers".to_string()];

    let blue_content = vec!["blue content".to_string(), "blue".to_string()];
    let red_content = vec!["red content".to_string(), "red".to_string()];

    let mut blue_writer = create_writer(is_zip, "blue");
    let mut red_writer = create_writer(is_zip, "red");

    blue_writer.write_strings(&header).unwrap();
    blue_writer.write_strings(&blue_content).unwrap();

    red_writer.write_strings(&header).unwrap();
    red_writer.write_strings(&red_content).unwrap();
}
```

Again, this is mostly personal preference and I think your solution was fine as-is. I just thought I'd give you another perspective on how else this could be implemented.

The next step for me would be error handling. Get rid of all the `unwrap()` and `expect()`, write a proper error enum with `thiserror` and propagate it through. Maybe add `miette` for bling.

I'm unsure, though, how well those tips translate to the `tacview-splitter` repository.

Comment: That is the type of input I was looking for. Thank you very much! Especially with regards to `Box` and `AsRef`.

Comment: I'll let this sit a couple more days if someone else feels inclined to write something, otherwise I will accept you answer as correct.

Comment: Just trying to understand all you've written. I found that `fn write_strings<S: Display>(...)` also works. Are there any tradeoffs to consider when choosing between the different Traits?

Comment: It depends what you intend. Your intention should reflect in the purpose of the chosen trait. `AsRef<str>` is everything that can be referenced to a `&str`, meaning, `&String` and `&str`. `Display` is intended for something else. Yes, the outcome is also a string, but `Display` means all types that can be presented to a human in a human readable format.  Yes, you could argue that `writeln!` means you want the content of your file to be explicitely human readable, and then yes, `Display` would probably be the correct choice. But that means that you can, for example also pass a `&f32` into it.

Comment: If that is your intention, that this function shall accept everything that is displayable, then yes, use that trait :) I just thought you explicitely want to take string-like objects. And string-like objects are usually passed via `&str`. But `&[&str]` does not work with `Vec<String>`, because the content would have to be converted to `&str` first. That's why in this case, I'd use the `AsRef<str>` instead. If it wasn't wrapped in a container, I'd definitely do `&str` instead.

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful!